# SP that returns all or filtered data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure (below) that returns the entire table. I am trying to make it so it will return the entire table OR return a certain date range in one Proc. Is this possible or do I need two procs for this? Thanks!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLeads]
AS
    SELECT name
         , lastname
         , title
         , company
         , address
         , address2
         , city
         , [state]
         , zip
         , country

    FROM
        lead
```

Comment: Are any of the columns dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLeads] 
    @LastNameSearch varchar(100) = null
AS 
    SELECT name 
         , lastname 
         , title 
         , company 
         , address 
         , address2 
         , city 
         , [state] 
         , zip 
         , country 
     FROM 
        lead 
     where
         ((@LastNameSearch is null) or (lastname = @LastNameSearch))
```

The above will result in a stored procedure that if you don't pass a parameter value to it, it'll return all of the data.  If you *do* pass a parameter value, it'll only return rows where `lastname = @LastNameSearch`.